# WP: inline styling background image - not working Safari 6.0 and under

Tags: php, wordpress, safari, inline-styles

I am getting the post/page featured image as an inline background image.

The code below works perfectly on most of the browsers, but not on Safari 6.0 and under.

On Safari 6.0 the inline style skips `background:url('xxx') no-repeat scroll xxx xxx / cover;` and goes directly to `min-height:(...)` .

The `background-attachment` is also not showing in the DOM.

Example of single project site: http://skarpsinn.no/prosjekter/oeva. Try with ex. Chrome and Safari 6.0.
This is my PHP-code for single pages - its pretty much the same on other pages.

```
            <?php if(is_single()): 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
            ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> 
                    <div class="featured_image" style="background: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>') no-repeat scroll <?php the_field('bg_vert_posisjon'); ?> <?php the_field('bg_hor_posisjon'); ?> / cover; min-height: 700px; position: relative; width: 100%; background-attachment: <?php the_field('bg_oppforsel'); ?>">
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="no_feature_image"></div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Any input will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with

```
background: url('http://skarpsinn.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/banner_oeva.png') no-repeat scroll center center / cover
```

If you remove the `/ cover` and put it on its own line it should work. The style would be:

```
background: url('http://skarpsinn.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/banner_oeva.png') no-repeat     scroll center center;
min-height: 700px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-attachment: initial;
background-size: cover;
```

(doing that worked for me on sarafi 5.1.7)

Comment: The case is that the entire `background:url()` is gone on Safari 6.0 (and below).

Comment: On Safari 5.1.7 the `background:url()` is still, but isn't working because of the `/ cover`.